# Position text on a plot with reverse axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display some statistics on a scatter plot using `geom_text()`, but the text disappears when I reverse the x-axis.

```
x = rnorm(20, mean = 10)
y = rnorm(20, mean =30)
R2 = cor(x, y)^2
R2 = signif(R2, 2)
df = data.frame(x, y)

#  It works on a normal axis.

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_text(label=paste("italic(R^2)==",R2), x = 10, y = 30, parse = T) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(6, 14)) 

#  But the text disappears when I reverse the x-axis:

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_text(label=paste("italic(R^2)==",R2), x = 10, y = 30, parse = T) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(14, 6), trans="reverse")
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `annnotate`: `p + annotate(geom = "text", label=paste("italic(R^2)==",R2), x=10, y=30, parse=T)` where p is your plot.

Comment: Or put your x and y in `aes` in `geom_text` ie   `geom_text(label=paste("italic(R^2)==",R2), aes(x = 10, y = 30), parse = T)`

Comment: Note also that by using `geom_text` with fixed `x` and `y` values, you're making `ggplot` write the exact same text over and over again in the same place, once for each row of your data. That's why it looks so jagged. @user20650's suggestion to use `annotate` results in the text being written only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will also write the text only once and will display the values as in the first example you provided:

```
labels <- data.frame(xval = 10, yval = 30, labeltext = paste("italic(R^2)==",R2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = xval, y = yval, label=labeltext), parse = T) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(14, 6), trans="reverse")
```